# How to setup USRP2

Tags: embedded, fpga, gnuradio, usrp

I am using USRP2 with RFX2400 Daughterboard. I plan to use the USRP2 for my project.

I downloaded the FPGA (bin) and the Firmware image and through the SD Card burner, I write it to a SD Card.

But I am not able to use the USRP2.

I connect the USRP2 to the Ubuntu system (Direct Connection through Ethernet). I run find_usrps and get the system error:

" No USRPS found"

Also, when I run und_find_devices, I get the error "No UHD devices found".

Please let me know if I am missing some obvious steps. When I turn on the USRP2, only LED F turns on.

I donot see the boot sequence as mentioned here: [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REDK7M-83WQ)

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and wonder if you still have the problem?

- Did you install the UHD driver?
- Did you veryify that it works properly?
- Do you have a GbE that is compatible with GR?